# I want to filter the clients of every agent individually. Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a view where I can show all the clients of specific agents via there PK.

I am not having error when I use Client.objects.all() as the queryset and it gets to show all of the clients. however I don't know how to filter clients via select pk for Url.

Please help.

Here's my Views.py

```
class AgentClientListView(OrganizerAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "agents/agent_client_list.html"
    context_object_name ="clients"

    def get_queryset(self):
        user= Agent.objects.get(pk=id)
        queryset = Client.objects.filter(user=user, agent__isnull=False).order_by('company_name')
        return queryset
```

My Urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AgentListView, AgentCreateView, AgentDetailView, AgentUpdateView, AgentDeleteView, AgentClientListView

app_name = 'agents'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', AgentListView.as_view(), name='agent-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', AgentDetailView.as_view(), name='agent-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', AgentUpdateView.as_view(), name='agent-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', AgentDeleteView.as_view(), name='agent-delete'),    
    path('<int:pk>/agent_client_list', AgentClientListView.as_view(), name='agent_client_list'),   
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', AgentDeleteView.as_view(), name='agent-delete'),   
    path('create/', AgentCreateView.as_view(), name='agent-create'),
]
```

Here's the Client Model

```
class Client(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    organization = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent", related_name="clients", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="clients", null=True, blank=True, default=6, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)

    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None) 
    baranggay = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=None)

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    phoned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    special_files = models.FileField(blank=True , null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

And HTML:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<section class="text-gray-600 body-font overflow-hidden">
    <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
      <div class="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="lg:w-1/2 w-full mx-auto">
            <h2 class="text-sm title-font text-gray-500 tracking-widest">AGENT</h2>
            <h1 class="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-4">{{ agent.user.first_name }} {{ agent.user.last_name }}</h1>
            <div class="flex mb-4">
              <a href="#" class="flex-grow text-blue-500 border-b-2 border-blue-500 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                Description
            </a>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="flex-grow border-b-2 border-gray-300 py-2 text-lg px-1">
                Update
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
            <div class="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
            <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
                <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                        <tr>
                        <th class="text-2xl px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100 rounded-tl rounded-bl">Client Name</th>
                        <th class="text-2xl px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100">Point Person</th>
                        <th class="text-2xl px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100">Date Added</th>
                        <th class="text-2xl px-4 py-3 title-font tracking-wider font-medium text-gray-900 text-sm bg-gray-100">Client Status</th>
                    </thead>
                        {% for client in clients %}
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <div>
                                        <td class="mt-3"><a href="{% url 'clients:client-detail' client.pk %}" class="text-xl hover:text-blue-500">{{ client.company_name }}</a></td>
                                        <td class="mt-3">{{ client.first_name }} {{ client.last_name }}</td>
                                        <td class="mt-3">{{ client.date_added }}</td>
                                        <td class="mt-3 px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-green-100 text-green-800"> {{ client.category }}</td>
                                    </div>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
{% endblock content %}
```

However I get this error:

```
TypeError at /agents/7/agent_client_list
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://techcrm.herokuapp.com/agents/7/agent_client_list
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 1776, in get_prep_value
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 31 May 2021 15:22:53 +0800
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you try client.id instead of client.pk? in your template?

Comment: I dont have problem in Href or in html

Comment: The problem I have is in Views.p when applying queryset

Comment: Can you share your Client model?

Comment: I have inputed the model and updated the question.. please check. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `id` in the `get_queryset`, since this refers to the builtin `id` function, not the primary key of the object.

You can obtain the URL parameters with `self.kwargs`:

```
class AgentClientListView(OrganizerAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'agents/agent_client_list.html'
    context_object_name ='clients'

    def get_queryset(self):
        agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Client.objects.filter(agent=agent, agent__isnull=False).order_by('company_name')
```

It might be better to directly filter on the primary key however, and thus work with *one* query instead of two:

```
class AgentClientListView(OrganizerAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'agents/agent_client_list.html'
    context_object_name ='clients'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Client.objects.filter(agent_id=self.kwargs['pk'], agent__isnull=False).order_by('company_name')
```

Comment: I get this error now:FieldError at /agents/7/agent_client_list
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_id' into field. Choices are: agent, agent_id, baranggay, category, category_id, city, company_name, date_added, email, first_name, id, last_name, mobile_number, organization, organization_id, phoned, region, special_files, street_address

Comment: @TyroneJasperGalang: then using `.filter(user=...)` makes no sense, and you likely made a "typo": it should be `agent` (and `agent_id`), not `user=...` or `user_id=...`.

Comment: However,  I changed user_id to agent_id and it worked!!! Thanks a lot!!